# How the value of n is decreased in recursion

Tags: javascript

For the recursion function below

```
function pow(x, n) {
  if (n == 1) {
    return x;
  } else {
    return x * pow(x, n - 1);
  }
}
```

How JS compiler determines to decrease the value of n recursively? I'm not decreasing the value like n--; still how the value is decreased automatically in each call?

Comment: It's right there... o.O -> `pow(x, n - 1)`

Comment: If pow(2, 4) then n would be always 4-1 right?

Comment: If `n === 4` then `pow(x, n - 1)` is `pow(x, 3)` -> `n === 3` then `pow(x, n -1)` is `pow(x, 2)` -> `n === 2`...

Answer (score 0):

`n--` is equal to `n = n - 1` while `n - 1` does not do anything unless you assign it to a variable.

In this case you do call `pow` function with `n - 1` meaning that you assigned the second parameter of the function to `n - 1` in each call.

```
pow(4, 4(this is n)) => pow(4, 3(this is n) => pow(4, 2(this is n) => pow(4, 1(this is n)
```